# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with package-info

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, netbeans, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I build my project as one executable jar with Maven on Windows, and I want to run my jar file on Linux.

I am receiving this error:

```
18:43:15.482 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BOOT-INF/classes/OPS/package-info (wrong name: OPS/package-info)] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BOOT-INF/classes/OPS/package-info (wrong name: OPS/package-info)
```

On Windows with same jdk1.8.0_121 it works fine, and I really don't know what could be wrong.

Plugins configuration from `pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
            <generatePackage>OPS</generatePackage>
            <schemas>
                <schema>
                    <url>************************?wsdl</url> 
                </schema>
            </schemas>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: have you tried to run first mvn install ?

Comment: BUILD SUCCESS with mvn install, the same error

Comment: Same problem, with spring-boot 1.5.x, this all worked fine previously. Can anyone at spring assist?

Comment: LInk to sample project reproducing the issue: https://github.com/nfedyk/spring-boot-jpa-issue-01